# RPI Amazon Kinesis Video Streams

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video, media-server, media

I was trying to follow the step in the tutorial below :

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/video-streams/raspberry-pi-tutorial/

I am stuck at step 5 of "Install Software Prerequisites":

Basically, I am supposed to copy a certain file to "/etc/ssl/cert.pem: "

That directory doesn't even exist. I don't get it. As anyone tried this tutorial before? Are we suppose to create a new directory?

Can someone please elaborate for me?

Comment: Howdy. Your link seems to be broken, could you please fix it? Could you please run `dpkg -s openssl` and post the line that reads `status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `openssl` is not installed. Check with

```
dpkg -s openssl
```

and look for the line that reads `status`. If it does not spell out `installed`, `openssl` needs to be installed. To do that just:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

That should include the creation of the required directory structure  `/etc/ssl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Much appreciated !!!! Do I create a filed named cert.pem in that folder and copy the content of SFSRootCAG2.pem in that file? Or should i create a file name SFSRootCAG2.pem ? Please help me.

Comment: @FritzFABO according to that amazon document you have linked it would seem that your should copy that file to `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`... Other answers here, e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76421/19949 suggest that it is not wise to manually copy stuff there. I need to leave a definitive answer to someone else.

Comment: What command can you use to copy that file to cert.pem? When I click on the link it doesn't download the file. It's opening a web page instead

Comment: @FritzFABO you should be able to "right click" it and select "save as" (or something similar). You could also copy the text if it is showing as a web page (all the stuff with *-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----* (and so on) is what you're looking for and copy that a text editor. If we are to believe you should copy that file to `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`, so following this guide that should be done. Again I cannot tell whether this is good or not (see the linked answer above).